# Are there words which sounds very similar in different languages, and which are proven not to be the result of cultural exchange?

Tags: historical-linguistics

Are there words which sounds very similar in different languages, and which are proven not to be the result of cultural exchange? For example, we know most words related to technology comes from English, so that's probably why computer is computadora in Spanish and kompyuta in Japanese. But is there proof that words coming from cultures isolated from each other having very similar sounds? (not counting onomatopoeias which are supposed to imitate how a noise sounds) . If so, can you give me some examples?

Comment: Here's an example: English "core" and Punjabi *kaur* "princess", pronounced the same. This is a sheer accident: is that what you're looking for. If not, what *are* you looking for?

Comment: The classic example is Mbabaram and English 'dog', which have the same meaning and similar pronunciation.

Comment: "For example, we know most words related to technology comes from English" I'd say, IT-related technology, not technology in general.

Comment: It is to be expected that for any two languages there will be a number of chance matches (ie words with similar form and meaning). Here's further discussion: http://zompist.com/chance.htm

Comment: @GastonÜmlaut that's interesting info, why dont you posts it as an answer?

Comment: @user6726 words with similar meaning and pronunciation. If my question isnt very descriptive, feel free to edit it

Comment: @ConstantineGeist not sure what you mean. For example, robot or television are adapted in many languages and they dont come from IT

Comment: They're all over the place. It's easy to find half-a-dozen words in any two languages that (a) resemble one another phonologically and (b) resemble one another semantically. Yucatec Maya _hól_ 'hole', for example. Larry Trask has a section on this problem in his _Historical Linguistics_ text; he examines the statistics and shows why it happens. The key term is "resemble" -- there are no systematic sound shifts, and the phonological and semantic "resemblances" are at the whim of the analyst, hence they're all over the place.

Comment: @jlawler is the conclusion that it is a statistical coincidence or are there some other reasons?

Comment: It's bound to happen if you relax your criteria for "resemblance", and they are always very vague and never systematic. There are only so many possible roots in a language and only so many things they can mean, so there are bound to be some hits; these can be multiplied by confirmation bias.

Comment: @Pablo, the word "robot" comes from Czech, not English (coined by Karel Čapek). The word "television" was coined by Russian scientist Constantin Perskyi in a French-language paper in 1900. Thanks for proving yourself wrong :)

Comment: @ConstantineGeist but it was imported to many other languages from English, not Czech.

Comment: It's to be proven, because you cannot deny the great influence of French and German in Europe. Say, the central and eastern portions of Europe usually borrowed technical terms from German, not English. Words, like Russian _lobzik_ "jigsaw" < German _Laubsäge_; _stameska_ "chisel" < German _Stemmeisen_ etc Before the XX century, English had little influence on other European languages, which is reflected in the vocabulary of Esperanto (1887) where words of English origin are relatively few, with most words stemming from French or German as the author did not feel English to be important enough.

Comment: @ConstantineGeist I can speak for spanish. We borrow most technological words from English, even if they come from another language. Japan for example, it has a syllabary where most words are adapted from English. They sound almost the same and it's easy to relate them even if you dont speak the language. Japan was forced to open to commerce by an american event which started the revolution that changed its country in 50 years from being in middle age to be a world power

Comment: Can you give examples outside of IT? In any case, the assumption "we know most words related to technology comes from English" is still wrong because it varies from country to country: Japanese as an extreme example of borrowing everything and French/Russian/German etc. where borrowings are limited to IT (when it comes to technology); and it also depends on what kind of time span we're talking about.

Comment: animation, baby car, dump car, air conditioning, hacker, personal computer, live action, etc. here you can see more, sort by language https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_gairaigo_and_wasei-eigo_terms

Comment: @Pablo I expected examples from Spanish, not Japanese. Japanese is a known extreme case. In any case, let's not create a chat out of this comment section.

Comment: "computer" comes from Latin, not from English. And most of the words in technology come from Latin or Greek.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think False Cognates : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_cognate might be what you are looking for.

Comment: false cognates from different languages, yes, that's what I'm looking for.

Comment: Happy to help! :)

Comment: @Pablo and as for an example, there is Farsi _behtar_ and English _better_.

Answer (score 6):

There is a Facebook group [Linguistic Coincidences & Curiosities](https://www.facebook.com/groups/linguisticcoincidences/) the members of which have been collecting such false cognates for years already. My favourites are the Latin and Malaysian "dua" which means "two" in both languages, there are also "reverse" coincidences like in Polish "tak" means "yes", and in Indonesian it means "no".

Answer (score 4):

I will give you a perfect example from Turkish and Japanese.
Turkish *iyi* and Japanese *ii* *いい* are read totally same. And more interestingly both of them have the very same meaning **good**. If you add Ural-Altaic hyptothesis, one can totally jump to the conclusion those 2 words have something in common.

I don't know story of the *いい* but I can tell about the *iyi*. In Istanbul Turkish it is *iyi*, but in most of the Anatolian accents it is *eyi* or *eyü*. It comes from the old Turkic *edgü*->*eḏgü*->*eygü*->*eyü*->*eyi*->*iyi*.

So actually both words have nothing in common except meaning.

Comment: What about Spanish vs Arabic articles? Given the long history of Arabian domination of Iberic Peninsula, the fact that Latin has no articles, and the striking similarity (*el* vs *al*), it seems to beg the conclusion that *el* is an import from Arabic. And yet, *el* comes from a Latin demonstrative.

Comment: It is very interesting! Do you know any paper or article about that? I checked wikipedia, but they didn't mention any source.

Answer (score 2):

Italian *strano* and Russian *stranno*, both meaning "strange" and totally unrelated. The English word "strange" is related to Italian one.

Answer (score 2):

The Nahuatl word **teotl** meaning *god* makes me think of the ancient greek **theos**, which has the same meaning [Theos — From Proto-Hellenic *tʰehós (whence also Mycenaean Greek  (te-o)), a thematicization of Proto-Indo-European *dʰéh₁s, s-suffixed noun derived from *dʰeh₁- (“to do, to put, to place”)].

Or even the Nahuatl verb **cochi** meaning *to sleep* reminds me of the french verb **coucher**, which means *to lay down* (although they are pronounced a bit differently, since the french "ch" sounds more like a "sh") , and is often used as to say *to go to bed* (e.g. "Je me couche" -> "I'm going to bed").

Answer (score 0):

There are probably thousands of such words.
Off-hand, I can give tr bardak/ru бардак, iv מטוס/fr matos.

It would be nice though to get the full list, in any pair (or more) of languages !

Seb

Comment: Because Russia never had significant contact with Turkic languages …

Comment: Both historically and linguistically your assumption is wrong. Even the word for language in russian is a Turkic word.

Comment: Russian бардак is Turkic borrowing.

Comment: @kabraxis Russian word for languge язык is not a borrowing, it is inherited from PIE and cognate to "language" and "tongue". It comes from PIE ***dnĝhuea̯s***.