# Is there any resource about "exceptional" examples of false cognates available?

Tags: reference-request, linguistic-typology, cross-linguistic, cognates

As an amateur I lack information about specialized resources for linguists. What I’m looking for is a list of stunning examples of false cognates in any discipline, that can be either exact matches, such as *mahina* which is both Hawaiian and Urdu for “month”, or near misses such as *rumai* and *rumah*, respectively Lithuanian and Malay for “house”, or be more different but meaning the same thing, such as *Ehecatl* and *Eolos*, the “wind deity” in Nahuatl and Greek. The criteria I’m looking for are that 1) the words should be longer than monosyllables, and 2) not being onomatopoeic, like *papalotl* and *papillion* in Nahuatl and French.

I understand that a resemblance between two words can be highly subjective, but I wonder if this type of resource exist? I would like to have a grasp of the extent of linguistic convergences across the world.

Comment: In principle there should be some such lists since they play a role in certain arguments against unmotivated "X is related to Y" claims. I take it you want more than an example or two, though – a decent-sized list.

Comment: Exactly, a sort of compendium of false cognates cherry-picked for their uniqueness. The longer the list (and the cognates), the better!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are there words which sounds very similar in different languages, and which are proven not to be the result of cultural exchange?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/22629/are-there-words-which-sounds-very-similar-in-different-languages-and-which-are)

Comment: See possible duplicate https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/22629/are-there-words-which-sounds-very-similar-in-different-languages-and-which-are; the accepted answer links to such a list.

Comment: There are dozens of words in every language that are "sort of the same" as words with "sort of the same" meaning in dozens of other languages. They're not hard to find. English _hole_ and Yucatec Maya /ho:l/, both with the same meaning, for instance. This is discussed very clearly, with examples, in Trask's _Historical Linguistics_.

Comment: What counts as "exceptional"? Those examples look like normal false cognates.

Comment: @curiousdannii - I explained it in my previous comment, anyway let me rephrase the question this way: How far do false cognates go in terms of word length? If the examples I gave are considered normal, then does a list of "less normal" false cognates of four, five or maybe more syllables exist? Of course monosyllabic words are the most frequent occurrence, so which are the longest known false cognates?