# Is there a linguistic term for words that can have the same meaning in different languages?

Tags: terminology, translation, meaning

The closest I can find is 'cognate' but that term is used for words that have similar etymology and phonetic characteristics but not necessarily the same or similar meaning in different languages.

The reason I said 'can have' in my question is because words in different languages can share a meaning but not all possible meanings. Each word in a language has a sort of meaning cloud which can overlap with a particular meaning of a word in another language, while other meanings are not shared between them.

Comment: Can you show some examples, please? I think, this would help understand and answer the question.

Comment: Any word that has a literal translation in another language is what I'm asking about. Perhaps I was being too specific in noting that while a word translates well with one meaning, the words can still have different, unshared meanings as well. I think this is pretty common, even with cognates. Words get used differently in different cultures and their meaning change.

Comment: I'd stick with cognates.

Comment: Maybe related: https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/22629/14731

Answer (score 9):

The term you are looking for (depending on etymological link) is *cognate*, or *[false cognate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_cognate)*:

> **False cognates** are pairs of words that seem to be [cognates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognate) because of similar sounds and meaning, but have different etymologies;

A famous example is the Mbabaram (extinct Australian Aboriginal language) word for dog, [*dog*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mbabaram_language#Word_for_"dog").

Some further examples are listed in the above Wikipedia page, e.g.:

- `English` *cut*; `Hindi` काट (*kaṭ*) "cutting"
- `English` *ache*; `Ancient Greek` ἄχος (*ákhos*) "pain, distress"
- `English` *lake*; `French` *lac*
- `English` *island*; `Spanish` *isla*
- `English` *much*; `Spanish` *mucho*
- `Spanish` *usted*; `Arabic` أستاذ (*ʾustāḏ*) "formal pronoun; teacher"
- `Japanese` 見る (*miru*); `Spanish` *mirar* "to watch"
- `Japanese` 秘伝 (*hiden*); `English` *hidden*
- `Japanese` 絵文字 (*emoji*); `English` *emoticon*
- `Japanese` ありがとう (*arigatō*); `Portuguese` (*obrigado*) "thank you"

Additionally, there is the term [*false friend*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_friend):

> **False friends** are words in two languages that [look](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homonym) or [sound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homophone) similar, but differ significantly in meaning.

Which would cover cognates and false cognates which differ in (at least one of) their meanings.

**Cognate false friends:**

- `English` *actual*; `Spanish` *actual* "current"
- `English` *preservative*; `Spanish` *preservativo* "condom"
- `English` ice; `Japanese` アイス (*aisu*) "ice-cream"

**Non-cognate false friends:**

- `English` *afraid*; `Russian` ефрейтор (*yefreitor*) "corporal"
- `Spanish` *afamada* "famous"; `Catalan` *afamada* "hungry*

An amusing example is 手紙 (composed of the characters 手 - hand, and 紙 - paper) which in Japanese means *tegami* "written message" but in Chinese means *shǒuzhǐ* "toilet paper".

Comment: *tegami* and *shǒuzhǐ* are not false friends, since they sound nothing alike  (and they're not cognates, either).  They merely happen to be represented in writing by the same characters; this is a coincidence of writing, not of language.  It's an artifact of a complex writing system that packs Chinese loan-morphemes and their conventional native translations into the same visual sign.

Comment: @boiko "False friends are words in two languages that **look** or sound similar, but differ significantly in meaning."

Comment: Spoken natural languages, like Japanese or Chinese, can't "look similar"; they're made of sounds.  (Sign languages can "look", but that's another story). Writing can "look similar", but writing is not language; it's an artificial system of signs built to represent it. A coincidence in signs of writing is a distinct phenomenon than a coincidence in actual linguistic words. The Russian word /sor/ may be represented by visual signs that look like the English /kɔp/ (both written *сор*); but this is a fact of writing, not of language, and therefore this coincidence is not one of false-friendness.

Comment: Some sources for this linguistic definition of "false friend" (i.e. based on language=sound and not on writing): David Crystal, *A Dictionary of Linguistics and Phonetics*; and Matthews, *The Concise Oxford Dictionary of Linguistics*.  But more than dictionaries, what matters is the basic conceptual distinction between language proper and writing. Phenomena of writing are not the same as linguistic phenomena—and phenomena of kanji/hànzì is not the same as phenomena of Japanese/Chinese. Homography is homography, not false-friendness; it's a different kind of thing, at another level.

Comment: Except the term "false friend" isn't limited to *spoken language*; it can also apply to written languages. A language is more than its spoken form.

Comment: For completeness and clarity, your examples of *cognate false friends* could include some that are not loans but direct inheritances.

Comment: @AdamBittlingmayer have done so.

Comment: "arigato" comes from Portuguese -- it is a borrowed word, neither a cognate or false cognate. It is written using hiragana but i wonder if it was ever written using katakana indicating that it is a foreign word?

Answer (score 4):

Besides cognates, there are also *chance coincidences* (say, Maya *vuh* and German *Buch* "book") when clearly unrelated words have the same sound and meaning in different languages.

Comment: How interesting is some supposed coincidences really stem from some historical transmission of the word. The Australian aborigine word for ""dog" mentioned above being "dog" of course certainly could be a coincidence but being that it is no doubt an ancient word, it could have been preserved for thousands of years from some protolanguage. I always thought the word for "hand" or "finger" should be similar in many apparently unrelated languages (but i do not think so); what is true is that in almost all languages the word for "one" is a single syllable and both "yes" and "no" are short words.