# Is there a term when two words have swapped definitions in one language or dialect compared to another?

Tags: terminology, dialects

My Peruvian friend informed me that a lemon is called "lima" in Peru while a lime is called "limón". This contrasts with some other Spanish dialects that use the word "limón" for lemon and "lima" for lime. Is there a word for this phenomenon? Additionally, what are some examples in English?

When the two words are from the same dialect, then what I'm describing is a pair of homonyms that have the same definitions—or more accurately, a pair of homonyms that have at least 2 definitions in common—but I don't know if this phenomenon is prevalent/important enough to have a word for it.

Comment: I don't know if there's a specific name for it, but these are examples of faux amis, where two lookalike words in two different languages/dialects sound similar.

Comment: @WavesWashSands, I would vote up your comment, but unfortunately I don't have that privilege. I've never heard of "faux amis", so thank you for teaching me that term.

Comment: The question is complicated because limas and limones are both green citrus products with the same flavor. (the idea of a green lemon makes no sense to a USAan; the idea of a yellow one makes no sense to a Mexican).

Comment: It’s not exactly an answer, but there are many examples of common words turning into slang words with an opposite positivity/negativity connotation. Everyone probably knows the outdated “sick” meaning cool, but a far popular one in my community (high school in Chicago) is “bad,” which means attractive. I bet there are coincidental examples of two words going opposite ways such that their slang meanings resemble each other’s standard meanings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe there is a specific term for this, but it could be described as a cognate mutual pair of cognate [false friends](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/26683/20700) (since both [*lima*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lima#Spanish) and [*limón*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lim%C3%B3n#Spanish) derive from Arabic لَيْمُون‎ (*laymūn*, “lemon, lime”)).

[This question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/1999/272638) on ELU has a number of British/American English examples, but none that come in mutual pairs unfortunately.

These wikipedia pages offer a more complete list:

- [List of words having different meanings in American and British English (A–L)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_words_having_different_meanings_in_American_and_British_English_(A%E2%80%93L))
- [List of words having different meanings in American and British English (M–Z)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_words_having_different_meanings_in_American_and_British_English_(M%E2%80%93Z))

A partial example that comes to mind is Asian/Oriental:

| Word | Br. En. meaning | Am. En. meaning |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `Asian` | From the Indian subcontinent | From East Asia |
| `Oriental` | From East Asia | From Asia |

Comment: Thanks for the pseudo-examples and etymology of "lima" and "limón"! The "Asian/Oriental" example is great; but as an American, I think of "Oriental" as meaning "from East Asia". I almost never use the term though since some find it offensive.

Answer (score -2):

In the U.S., lemons and limes are similar, except limes tend to be smaller.  The -on at the end of "lemon" appears to be an augmentative form, so it might mean "big lime".  For the term "augmentative", see [Spanish diminutive and augmentative terminations](https://www.123teachme.com/learn_spanish/augmentative_terminations_theory_b), which gives an example "una mujer - woman ---> un mujerón: a big, strong woman".

I'm not claiming anything about the actual etymologies, but just pointing out that it makes some sense to call a lemon a big lime.  Also, I've seen some rather large fruits called "lima" in Brazil, so I think there may be some confusion about what to call these similar fruits.

I doubt there is anything general or interesting going on here.

Comment: Does not answer the question, which is about terminology.